# filtering grid with a datetime range asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm a beginner in asp.net MVC. I try to create an app which allow to filter a grid of data. I have an error when I want to filter the data based on a date(in my app the field is "asked_date").
I created 2 parameters in controllers: DateTime SelectedDateStart, DateTime SelectedDateEnd. In the controllers, I use this parameters like this:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string SortOrder, string SelectedDesk, string SelectedProgramme, string SelectedCountry, DateTime SelectedDateStart, DateTime SelectedDateEnd)
    {
        var missions = from s in db.missions_supportmission
                       select s;

        //Filtres 
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedDesk))
        {
            missions = db.missions_supportmission.Include(s => s.organization_desk).Where(a => a.desk_id == SelectedDesk);
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedProgramme))
        {
            missions = db.missions_supportmission.Include(s => s.organization_programme).Where(a => a.programme_id== SelectedProgramme);
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedCountry))
        {
            missions = db.missions_supportmission.Include(s => s.organization_hi_country).Where(a => a.country_id == SelectedCountry);
        }
        //Filtres dates
        missions = db.missions_supportmission.Where(a => a.asked_date > SelectedDateStart).Where(a => a.asked_date < SelectedDateEnd);
        ViewBag.SelectedDateStart = SelectedDateStart;
        ViewBag.SelectedDateEnd = SelectedDateEnd;

        return View(missions.ToList());
    }
```

In the view I have this:

```
    <h3>Date</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="Date">De</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="date" class="form-Date" id="id" value="ViewBag.DateStart" onchange="form.submit();">
        </div>
        <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="Date">A</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="date" class="form-Date" id="id" value="ViewBag.DateEnd" onchange="form.submit();">
        </div>
    </div>
```

In the class I have this:

```
    public partial class missions_supportmission 
    {public int id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime asked_date { get; set; }
```

When I debug I have the following error:

> "System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'SelectedDateStart' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.DateTime, System.DateTime)' in 'MissionsDF.Controllers.MissionsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Nom du paramètre : parameters"

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The exception indicates `SelectedDateStart` contains null value, which expects `DateTime?` data type. Also `<input type="date" class="form-Date" id="id" value="ViewBag.DateStart" onchange="form.submit();">` is not a good way to create `DateTime` input, why not using `@Html.TextBoxFor` or `@Html.EditorFor` helper?

Comment: Your inputs do not have `name` attributes - they do not post back anything.

Comment: Also you have other issue - `onchange="form.submit();"` definitions are redundant and you can simply handle it from a class selector, or add a button to handle form submit.

Comment: I tried to change my code like this: @Html.Editor("SelectedDateStart", new { onchange = "form.submit();" }); Have i to change someting in the controller?

Comment: If the `DateTime` editor can have null value, make sure the parameter declared as `DateTime?` and put checking against null. Otherwise you need to set default value for `DateTime` to avoid the error.

Comment: I declared parameters as DateTime? I don't have errors anymore but my grid of data is empty now.

Comment: Send your dateTime as `String` to your ViewBag and in your view try convert this to `DateTime` using razor. If you have problems with ViewBag use sessions.

Comment: I don't know how to send a dateTime as String to a ViewBag. Can you show me an example of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
I decided to declare the parameters "SelectedDateStart" ans "SelectedDateEnd" as `DateTime?` and put checking against null in the controller like this (in the meantime, I decided to replace the viewbags by viewmodel method):

```
if (model.SelectedDateStart.HasValue && model.SelectedDateEnd.HasValue)
        {
            model.OnePageOfMissions = db.missions_supportmission
                     .Where(a => a.asked_date > model.SelectedDateStart && a.asked_date<model.SelectedDateEnd)
                     .OrderBy(a => a.asked_date)
                     .Select(s => s).ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10);
        }
```